# Construction of kriegen + etwas + Partizip II

Tags: verb, verb-usage

For the various use cases of *kriegen*, [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/kriegen) shows a specific usage and construction of *kriegen + Noun + Partizip II* (Bedeutung 1.g). For example:

> Wir haben Geld ausgezahlt gekriegt.
>
> Wir haben ein großes Pensum aufgeladen gekriegt.
>
> Ich kriegte einen guten Tropfen eingeschenkt.

I have not seen this construct before and would like to know if this is unique to the verb *kriegen* or there is a  more general rule which applies to other verbs as well.

Comment: This feels at least very "low level" to me, if not outright wrong. Standard German would probably be a construction with "bekommen", like "Wir haben Geld ausgezahlt bekommen".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb *»kriegen«* has a synonym that is even more frequently used and is a part of high quality standard German whereas *»kriegen«* is rather a word mainly used in colloquial speech. This synonym is *»bekommen«* and it is used the same way as *»kriegen«:*

> Wir haben Geld ausgezahlt **bekommen.**
> <sup>We **got** money paid out.</sup>
> Wir haben ein großes Pensum aufgeladen **bekommen.**
> <sup>We **got** a big workload loaded on us.</sup>
> Ich **bekam** einen guten Tropfen<sup>1</sup> eingeschenkt.
> <sup>I **got** poured a good wine.</sup>

<sup>1</sup><sub>*»Ein guter Tropfen«* is a synonym for a good glass of wine.</sub>

The usage of the word *»kriegen«* is discouraged in formal speech. To use it is not wrong, but *»bekommen«* is better style.

---

Be aware, that German *»bekommen«* and English *»to become«* are false friends. Here are the correct translations:

- etwas **bekommen** = to **get** something
- etwas **werden** = to **become** something

> Lisa **bekommt** ein Auto. = Lisa **gets** a car.
> Lisa **wird** Lehrerin. = Lisa **becomes** a teacher.